# Removing the Openstack Compute Service from a controller node

Tags: ubuntu, cloud, openstack, openstack-nova

Can you explain how to remove the Compute Service (Nova) from a controller node in OpenStack?

I am using Linux Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 1):

You want to go through the same steps as removing a compute node. Surprisingly, this not well documented; in particular I don't see instructions on the OpenStack documentation site at all. However, the [instructions at Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E90981_01/E90982/html/nova.html) look good to me.

Summary: Disable the compute service, so that no new instances are scheduled. Migrate all instances away. Remove the node from Nova's database with `openstack compute service delete`. Do the same with Neutron agents. Now you can remove the nova-compute packages and the Neutron agent packages.